# Linking URL to SSRS field, no data on report server

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

My report has a link to a resource I loaded to the report server. I've used some very helpful previous [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003013/open-ssrs-url-in-new-window) to get to this code which tests just fine:

**Code1**

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://reportserverlink/test.pdf ','_blank'))
```

I have the text box properties -> actions -> go to URL configured. The text box holds a field from my dataset and I want to bring up the corresponding PDF when clicked. Here is the code:

**Code2**

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://reportserverlink/" & Fields!PDFFileName.Value & ','_blank'))
```

However, when I deploy the report with code2, the report has no data. The header/footer works, the column headers are there; just no data. The report preview in BIDS gives the appearance it is working.

Any thoughts? And thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the final parameters in the url are not being concatenated properly.

'http://reportserverlink/" & Fields!PDFFileName.Value & '

If you are trying to concatenate a value inside a variable inside a String you should try something like 'http://reportserverlink/?' + foo1 + '&' + foo2

Comment: Yes, I have and tested again now. The final URL works correctly.