# SSRS link with PDF failing

Tags: javascript, pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

In a SSRS2008R2 report with an action linked to a field value; this code is working (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389538/ssrs-2008-create-url-link-to-pdf-file-on-file-server-for-each-cell-in-report-ta)):

```
="FILE:\\E:\SharedServer\"+Fields!PDFFileName.Value
```

Then I wrapped it with JavaScript to open in a new window and it is failing.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('FILE:\\E:\SharedServer\'+Fields!PDFFileName.Value','_blank'))"
```

The mouse hovers shows a hyperlink but when I click on it, absolutely nothing happens. I had [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810803/linking-url-to-ssrs-field-no-data-on-report-server) before but this is a new issue. I've tried several minor variations with the quotation marks but have not hit upon the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some double quotes and a `+` sign:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('FILE:\\E:\SharedServer\" + Fields!PDFFileName.Value + "','_blank'))"
```

But I'm not even sure if that will work; some other posts (like [Opening a file in local file system in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534297/opening-a-file-in-local-file-system-in-javascript)) indicate that javascript can't do this.

Comment: The code is working (when I get Chrome to show the report). And, thanks for the link to the IE issue.