# Opening a URL From SSRS

Tags: javascript, reporting-services

I am trying to open a URL in an SSRS report in a new window. I have used the following expression: `="javascript:void(window.open(escape("+ Fields!ImagePath.Value + "),'_blank'))"`. Nothing happens when I click on the field `(Fields!ImagePath.Value)`. I have also tried removing the "escape" expression. I've also used the REPLACE function in my SQL statement to replace the "\" with %5C. On the occasion when it has more or less worked, the backslashes are dropped entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This worked: ="javascript:void(window.open('" + Replace(Fields!ImagePath.Value, "\", "/") + "','_blank'));" The clue, for me, was swapping out the back-slash for a forward-slash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. [Open SSRS URL in New Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003013/open-ssrs-url-in-new-window?rq=1)

```
="javascript:void(window.open('" & Fields!ImagePath.Value & "'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('" + Fields!ImagePath.Value + "','_blank'));"
```

Comment: I get an error saying the image is invalid. The path that is returned is http://intranet.xxx.com/sqlReports/FFScannedImage.php?image=003VENDORPREQUALIFICATIONp71567.pdf and the backslashes have been dropped. The correct path is http://intranet.xxx.com/sqlReports/FFScannedImage.php?image=003%5CVENDOR%5CPREQUALIFICATION%5C16071567.pdf

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. Can you paste those links as code blocks so that characters don't get replaced?

Comment: The full path is "http://intranet.xxx.com/sqlReports/FFScannedImage.php?image=003\VENDOR\PREQUALIFICATION\12076029.PDF" When the URL comes up, it says invalid image and that's because all of the backslashes get dropped. It displays in the browser as "http://intranet.xxx.com/sqlReports/FFScannedImage.php?image=003VENDORPREQUALIFICATION12076029.PDF". The field has the entire URL. I've tried using the REPLACE function where the "\" is replaced with %53.

Comment: Can you show how you are using the replace function in your expression? Also, I think backslash should be %5C...

Comment: Replace(Field.ImagePath.Value, "\", "%5C") I also tried it in the stored procedure: REPLACE(ImagePath, '\', '%5C') AS ImagePath.

Comment: It looks right to me but we don't have backslashes in any of our URLs. You night need to ask this as a separate question.