# Opening an SSRS URL in new window problems with https

Tags: javascript, sql, reporting-services

We're trying to make a go to URL action for a report in SSRS and then have it open up a separate report in the report server with the specified parameters.  This may be real simple but the problems we're having is that:

We run into the "Your connection is not private" problem which makes sense because it is an internal website.

Or our syntax is horribly wrong.

So we've very minimal javascript exposure other than what IT has made for us in the past which we pick from when we need it.

Here's what we've tried (to just get to the url we will add the parameters later):

```
="javascript:void(window.open('https://internal/my.org/departments/supplychain/analyticsreports/Report Library/Single Item Reorder Point Review.rdl'))"
```

We've tried a variation of this that include our report server Globals!ReportServerUrl but we can't seem to figure out the correct way to utilize it.

Tried this thread [Open SSRS URL in New Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003013/open-ssrs-url-in-new-window), but to no avail.

In the end we would like the url not to be hard coded in as things are consistently changing.

If this has been answered before please point me there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found this article that might be of assistance.  It deals with embedding JavaScript launch of a new report in a separate tab.  Hope it helps:

https://direit.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/ssrs-use-custom-javascript-to-call-a-report-in-a-new-tabwindow/

Comment: I did see that article when we were troubleshooting before. Not sure if it would solve our problem and we also don't have access to that file folder as we are not the dba.  Although it would be nice to add a function that could handle our case.

Comment: I understand; however you could try to take the expression in your report where they are calling the JavaScript function in the file and type in the code to launch